# View navigation in GroovyFX

Tags: groovy, javafx, groovyfx

I'd like to adapt a MVVM WPF app to GroovyFX. I don't have so much experience in Groovy nor in GroovyFX itself, and there isn't so much information available.

The design consist in a main window with a panel inside. When the user, let's say, pushes a button the app deletes the central panel children and inserts the new "node tree" that conforms the target view.

Let's see some code

```
import groovyx.javafx.GroovyFX
import groovyx.javafx.SceneGraphBuilder
import static groovyx.javafx.GroovyFX.start
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

def controller = new MainWindowController()
def loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("gui.fxml"));
def myPane = loader.load();

start
{
    stage(title: "Tasks!", x: 100, y: 100, width: 400, height: 400, visible: true,
        style: "decorated", onHidden: { println "Close"})
    {
        scene(fill: GROOVYBLUE)
        {
            vbox(spacing: 10, padding: 10)
            {
                button(text:"Show!",onAction:{ controller.activityPanel.getChildren().clear() controller.activityPanel.getChildren().add(myPane)})
                controller.activityPanel=stackPane()
            }
        }
     }
}
```

When the user presses the button the stackPane located inside the main window receives the contents of myPane and this "view" is shown.
The question is

1. How can I define this view "myPane" by code? I have only found the fxml solution.
2. If the fxml is the only way, do you know any sample code about how to instantiate a controller class and bind its members using GroovyFX?

This idea is similar to the jfx-flow project but in GroovyFX.

Answer (score 1):

for #2 you can do...

```
fxml resource("/FXMLDemoInline.fxml"), {
    buttonCSSID.onAction {
        labelCSSID.text = "Clicked - CSS";
    }
    buttonFXID.onAction {
        labelFXID.text = "Clicked - FXML";
    }
}
```

This is [from the demos](https://github.com/groovyfx-project/groovyfx/blob/master/src/demo/groovy/FXMLDemo.groovy)

For #1 you can use the `build(Script)` instance method in the GroovyFX builder.  Just write the script as though you were in the start method of GroovyFX and references the script class.